# Understand orient-db logic

Tags: sql, orientdb

I'm new in OrientDB/grahps and I'm trying to understand it's logic clearly.

Let's say there are vertexes Movies 1:n Genres with SortOf edge. I would like to know other genres that have movies that are 'Comedy'.

After reading docs I'd thought that it should be something like that:

```
SELECT expand(in('SortOf').out('SortOf')[name<>'Comedy'])
FROM Genre WHERE name = 'Comedy'`
```

It returns 0 records.
If i remove `<>` I get all the list, and even can filter by `=`:

```
SELECT expand(set(in('SortOf').out('SortOf')[name='Drama']))
FROM Genre WHERE name='Comedy'
```

Returns 1 record.
Right now I have result with query below:

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(set(in('SortOf').out('SortOf')))
FROM Genre WHERE name = 'Comedy')
WHERE name NOT LIKE 'Comedy'`
```

Again, it returns 0 records if I put `name!='Comedy'` instead of `LIKE`.

What is the right way for this query? Where should I place `count` to see   how many movies in each genre?

**UPDATE**

I've replaced `!=` with `<>`, so working query is:

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(set(in('SortOf').out('SortOf')))
FROM Genre WHERE name='Comedy')
WHERE name<>'Comedy'`
```

But first query still not working. What am I missing? Else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you're looking for is **<>**

See [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Where.html#operators) for other operators.

**UPDATE** In your case:

```
create class Movie extends V
create class Genre extends V
create class SortOf extends E

create vertex Movie set name = 'm1'

create vertex Genre set name = 'Comedy'
create vertex Genre set name = 'Drama'


create edge SortOf from (select from Movie where name = 'm1') to (select from Genre where name = 'Comedy')
create edge SortOf from (select from Movie where name = 'm1') to (select from Genre where name = 'Drama')


select from (
    select expand(in('SortOf').out('SortOf')) from Genre where name = 'Comedy'
) where name <> 'Comedy'
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. I believe it's an identical case to yours.

Comment: My mistake! Updated. Last one is working, but not the first one. Why is that? And can query be shorter?

Comment: No. For what I know, that's not supported (yet).